# Using Chome's omnibar to search a specific site - how does it work?

Tags: google-chrome, search

I'm a heavy Chrome user and while typing in yet another url, I noticed a strange behavoir whereby the ombnibar (url bar) changed to say "Search MyCo JIRA:" and allowed me to directly search my jira site via the private search page. Same works for wikipedia, confluence, and others.

How does chrome recognize this site is searchable and how to submit the request?

Here is the key combo I came across:
- open chrome and place cursor into an empty omnibar.
- type

```
 wikipedia.org:<space>
```

that is the domain, a colon, and a space.

The omnibar changes to show a spyglass button saying "Search Wikipedia (en):"

This is so cool I want to know how to do this to my site.

Comment: What do you mean by "do this to my site"?

Comment: Is this the same thing as when (for example) you type in Youtube.com and press <Tab> to search?

Comment: I would like to know how this works so I can identify other sites that support it and find/make an extension for my blog.

Comment: Yes, tab has the same effect. Nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be thinking about [OpenSearch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSearch).  Here's how to add it to your site:

[Implement OpenSearch on your site in 5 minutes](http://blog.unto.net/add-opensearch-to-your-site-in-five-minutes)

Here are some details on how Chrome handles the tab-to-search:

[Chromium.org](http://dev.chromium.org/tab-to-search)

If you want complete Google search integration on your site, see here:

[Google SiteSearch](http://www.google.com/sitesearch/)

Comment: Cool! seems Amazon.com is OpenSearch-able as well. Thanks

Comment: OpenSearch appears to be very flexible.  It would definitely make your site impressive to visitors.